# Regex to trim special characters from the given string

Tags: java, regex

I have extracted data from the source and now it's a set of tokens. These tokens contains junk characters or special characters in the end or sometimes in the beginning. For example I have following set..

- manufactured traffic
- (devices
- traffic-calming)
- traffic-
- synthetic,
- artificial turf.)

This data should be as following respectively...

- manufactured traffic
- devices
- traffic-calming
- traffic
- synthetic
- artificial turf

To purify this string set, I have implemented below method, that is working properly. [See on regex101.com...](https://regex101.com/r/jrf53h/1)

```
public Filter filterSpecialCharacters() {
    String regex = "^([^a-z0-9A-Z]*)([a-z0-9A-Z])(.*)([a-z0-9A-Z])([^a-z0-9A-Z]*)$";
    set = set
        .stream()
        .map(str -> str.replaceAll(regex, "$2$3$4"))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return this;
}
```

But I am still not satisfied with the regex I am using because I have a large set of data. Want to see if there's better option.

Comment: what the excepted separator between two parts of work, you want to keep hyphen dot...

Comment: I'd check the performance against a strategy that uses two separate `map()` calls with simpler regexes, one to strip special characters from the start and another to strip them from the end.

Comment: @TedHopp you mean perhaps `set = set.stream()
        .map(str -> str.replaceFirst("^\\p{Punct}*", ""))
        .map(str -> str.replaceFirst("\\p{Punct}*$", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: @YCF_L - Yeah, something like that. Although OP might want to use `[^a-z0-9A-Z]` instead of `\\p{Punct}` if things like foreign-script letters should also be stripped.

Comment: How are you "extracting" the data, and what are you extracting it from? Is it possible that if you parsed the XML or JSON or whatever correctly you wouldn't have any data cleansing to do at the end?

Comment: @YCF_L not special separator there, but string can have any character in middle, but not in the end and beginning.

Comment: @DavidConrad I've parsed a PDF and used x-y co-ordinates given by Apache PDFBox to extract tokens. So this noise also got captured :P

Comment: did you tried my solution!!

Comment: Actually I have tried @sln 's answer, that is working fine. But your answer is difficult to understand. I didn't get that {Punct}. How it works! So I was exploring more your answer.

Comment: `\p{Punc}` is a pre-defined Posix character class. (You need to double the backslash when specifying it as a Java string constant.) It's equivalent to `[-!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]` -- namely, all the punctuation characters in US-ASCII. It's not quite the same thing as `[^a-z0-9A-Z]` because of space and control characters (like tab or newline) and because it doesn't deal with characters outside of US-ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use regex for these kind of simple trims. Parse the string and trim it. The code is big, but is surely faster than regex.

```
public static List<String> filterSpecialCharacters(List<String> input) {
    Iterator<String> it = input.iterator();
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    // For all strings in the List
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String s = it.next();
        int endIndex = s.length() - 1;
        // Get the last index of alpha numeric char
        for (int i = endIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (isAlphaNumeric(s.charAt(i))) {
                endIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        boolean startCopying = false;
        // Parse the string till the last index of alpha numeric char
        for (int i = 0; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            // Ignore the leading occurrences non alpha-num chars
            if (!startCopying && !isAlphaNumeric(s.charAt(i))) {
                continue;
            }
            // Start copying to output buffer after(including) the first occurrence of alpha-num char 
            else {
                startCopying = true;
                out.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        // Add the trimmed string to the output list.
        output.add(out.toString());
    }

    return output;
}

// Updated this method with the characters that you dont want to trim
private static boolean isAlphaNumeric(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Please test this code to see if it satisfies your conditions. I see that this is almost 10 times faster than the regex trims (used in other answers). 
Also, if performance is important to you, then I recommend you to use `Iterator` to parse the `Set`, instead of `stream/map/collect` functions.

Comment: I have seen all three approaches, and all are working. But when it comes to performance, your code is really faster. I'm turning my method as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to use `\p{Punct}` to remove all this punctuation `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`

```
String regex = "^\\p{Punct}*([a-z0-9A-Z -]*)\\p{Punct}*$";
set = set.stream()
        .map(str -> str.replaceAll(regex, "$1"))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

=>[synthetic, devices, traffic-calming, manufactured traffic , artificial turf]
```

---

take a look at this [Summary of regular-expression constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

---

Or like [@Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364451/regex-to-trim-special-characters-from-the-given-string#comment89701907_51364451) mention in comment you can use two maps one remove special characters from begging the second to remove them from the end :

```
set = set.stream()
        .map(str -> str.replaceFirst("^[^a-z0-9A-Z]*", ""))
        .map(str -> str.replaceFirst("[^a-z0-9A-Z]*$", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single passive regex that works the same every time.

Globlly Find `(?m)^[^a-z0-9A-Z\r\n]*(.*?)[^a-z0-9A-Z\r\n]*$`
Replace `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/tGFbLm/1

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # BOL
 [^a-z0-9A-Z\r\n]*     
 ( .*? )                       # (1), Passive content to write back
 [^a-z0-9A-Z\r\n]* 
 $                             # EOL
```